# Javascript opens xml but dont do the tasks inside function

Tags: javascript, php, html

> This code just opens the file but doesnt perform function abc mentioned.

```js
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

   var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
    abc(xhttp);
    }
};       
 xhttp.open("GET", "qwe.xml", true);
xhttp.send();
 
 


 function abc(xml){
 
 
 
 var xmlDoc = xml.responseXML;
  
    var x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('xyz')[40];
 
    var y = x.childNodes[0];
 
 
   

document.getElementById("cell3").innerHTML = y.nodeValue;
 
 
 }
 </script>
```

> This performs the function but I dont want this way because I will be running the function in loop.

```js
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">


 
 


 function abc(xml){
 
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
    abc(xhttp);
    }
};       
 xhttp.open("GET", "qwe.xml", true);
xhttp.send();
 
 var xmlDoc = xml.responseXML;
  
    var x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('xyz')[40];
 
    var y = x.childNodes[0];
 
 
   

document.getElementById("cell3").innerHTML = y.nodeValue;
 
 
 }
 </script>
```

The javascript in real has many functions but I am just mentioning only one which I have issue with

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What i believe is happening is that your code isn't finding the page. Run this code to see if the page your are executing is found.

```js
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (xhttp.readyState == 4) {
    if (xhttp.status == 200) {
      alert('Found Page');
    } else {
      alert('Page not Found');
      console.log('Page Status is: ' + xhttp.status);
    }
  }
};
xhttp.open("GET", "qwe.xml", true);
xhttp.send();
```

`xhttp.status == 200` Is the status of the page that is returned.

Here is the list of statuses and what they mean.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes

A quick list that you will most likely see is the following.

```
200 = Everything OK
301 = Page Redirect
404 = Page not found
500 = Server Error
```